# Issue while adding node in existing cluster from different cloud provider in kubernetes?

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, docker, kubernetes, azure-devops

We have a running kubernetes cluster with master and 3 worker nodes on azure cloud. Now we want to add a new node which is running on AWS cloud. When tried to add this node into existing cluster then we are getting error as.

```
Container runtime network not ready: NetworkReady=false reason:NetworkPluginNotReady message:docker: network plugin is not ready: cni config uninitialized
```

but if the node is existing on same cloud provider then it is working fine.

Please let me know if anyone faced the same issue.

Comment: I guess networking plugin is not installed on the node?

Comment: Please provide more details about - how are your bootstrapping you cluster configuration with config details. Are you using consul?

Comment: I am just joining a new worker node.

Answer (score 0):

As per documentation [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/create-cluster-kubeadm/#pod-network).

Please select one of the tabs to see installation instructions for the respective third-party Pod Network Provider.

> The network must be deployed before any applications. Also, CoreDNS will not start up before a network is installed. kubeadm only supports Container Network Interface (CNI) based networks (and does not support kubenet).

So please verify the "status" of your cluster:

```
kubectl get nodes -o wide
kubectl get pods --all-namespaces
```

For "Cross Cloud Kubernetes cluster" please take a look [here](https://medium.com/google-cloud/experimenting-with-cross-cloud-kubernetes-cluster-federation-dfa99f913d54)